# React router's switch doesn't work when separated from Router in a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I tried to separate the `Router` and `Switch` components in 2 different files, for the sake of modularization, but it won't work and the errors don't appear to make sense...

The main file, `App.jsx`, renders something like this:

```
<Router>
    <div>
        <Nav />
        <AppRouter />
    </div>
</Router>
```

You can notice that the Router contains only 1 child, which is a div.

The `AppRouter` renders something like this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/list" exact component={List} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

While the `Nav` simply contains a list of `Link`s:

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
```

As far as I know, since `Router` contains only 1 child and since a `Switch` is supposed to work with several children, this code should be alright.

However this code fails:

```
Uncaught Error: A <Router> may have only one child element
```

[You can use a live example here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/9jnoy48j0y)

---

I also noticed a strange behaviour: when I remove some `Route`s so there is only 1 `Route` left, there is no more error, but then the navigation doesn't work anymore (it changes the URL, nothing else).

---

What is happening there and how do I fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import **Switch** as like `import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";` in your `AppRouter.jsx`.

You can't import `BrowserRouter as Switch`